# How does RingCT prevent doublespend ?

Tags: ringct, double-spending-attack

For what I know about RingCT it use fake outputs to mask the amount that is transaction between address's, how do we know that the fakeoutputs are correct and that is noone messing with them?

Comment: Same way as right now: key images.

Answer (score 7):

RingCT does not create fake outputs. Here is a good dumbed-down explanation of its principle: [ELI5: How does RingCT work?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/880/eli5-how-does-ringct-work)

Therefore there is no difference between "normal" transactions and RingCT ones in terms of double-spend prevention: it is handled in the exact same way using key images.

Comment: In practice it does produce fake outputs though, I'm pretty sure, eg explained [here](http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/can-i-manually-check-consistency-of-pedersen-commitments-in-ringct?rq=1) -- hidden are the real values that sum to 0 ( or 0 - fees if fees are transparently valued) and each transaction has a public 'fake' value of 0.