# Can I manually check consistency of Pedersen Commitments in RingCT?

Tags: ringct, cryptography, transaction-data, confidential-transactions

Even though I fully trust the math behind RingCT and I know no moneroj can be created out of thin air, sometimes I'd like to see for myself the consistency of the Pedersen Commitment before/after any given transaction (ie. they sum up to the same value).

If I do `print_tx 914b3d1367f10ee95e4aad793e07dab20c2c7106c63593821d7300a7a4cb1a34` on the testnet, I see some information among quite a chunk of data:

```
Found in blockchain at height 834232
...(chunk)...
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 0, 
  "vin": [ {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 13206, 10439, 3501, 19878, 1840
        ], 
        "k_image": "85e8e93b7dcee586a427f7892d42e9d6127231261ee794bed0b0a17d3de4df38"
      }
    }, {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 41271, 5033, 2562, 21, 95
        ], 
        "k_image": "0606c5bdb3f04cf602a1a50b76253b4fac1f86aa283ecae56af05eeab361cf2f"
      }
    }, {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 19118, 15576, 2754, 6750, 4652
        ], 
        "k_image": "68b8fa419a663433d4aac7cb807905fa4adf94873da346578a82ed9091a09f8f"
      }
    }, {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 22933, 15530, 3305, 5886, 1244
        ], 
        "k_image": "d8fe30c97b13beed710b2609dc1ce06e85b08a741fb7d7a5960810ff5de47a7e"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [ {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "5cde923e1712422d71dd577b35681125912b4c4a538444193ab6e271fd7a43a8"
      }
    }, {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "ca3cc9d51a037322e3f3ff2fe771e85c26628b7e2c1163c3e1e29515885c4163"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "extra": [ 1, 235, 1, 181, 37, 243, 100, 198, 158, 197, 43, 164, 39, 167, 190, 249, 250, 228, 251, 153, 212, 248, 165, 112, 95, 210, 238, 138, 151, 158, 243, 238, 50
  ], 
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 2, 
    "txnFee": 30000000000, 
    "pseudoOuts": [ "276f03ba8c7852cb545830f7fedcdcd08789675d2a6c265bea236d0de90f6b11", "c611cc551db3b05ad6e5dba4ce89a8eeeb18317d8b565031941e98b6b9b8db4f", "8a088f1ccd11dd1633a663538faa9cb18c157b4fd37c421697a6356b4d7a98f6", "9e1238add1c1a4712904e5d5d8913482dcd6d31af166bc73918fd8148a42f22b"], 
    "ecdhInfo": [ {
        "mask": "c626b75f726e88a26fc74c1bb508fa9358c0896a7635d0f1256c7f43f0217706", 
        "amount": "63c1d97047ff515ccd5ca271f4e5013b9c1092c25307207a0ff037b13f492c00"
      }, {
        "mask": "73b4367f9b143c0a453598f85761698c4548e890fa52a05b4e28183126525008", 
        "amount": "81b48b46e79b458a234ad36d3d0890f89e30d50cc18a687dd94fd0ef3417da0f"
      }], 
    "outPk": [ "f9cabc6b0fd32822feb3e13c70b54b2cdc2a3ce7c88ac661c29ab20732e2974f", "cfb010382648e11d7d5744fe8051c8606f31c901f9ede5b7e392f73790f9e7f8"]
  }, 
  "rctsig_prunable": {
    "rangeSigs": [ {
...(chunk)...
```

I guess `key_offsets` point to the outputs `P_i^j` and `outPk` represent the output commitments `C_{i,out}` as in [MRL-0005](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf) (page 9, Definition 4.1). What I would like to do is to check that `i`-th member of `R` actually matches `\sum_{j}P_i^j + \sum_{j}C_i^j - \sum_{k}C_{k,out}`. Can I do this by myself easily, eg. by using [Luigi1111's JavaScript code](https://steemit.com/monero/@luigi1111/understanding-monero-cryptography-privacy-part-2-stealth-addresses)? How can I get `P_i^j` and `C_i^j` and `i`-th member of `R` from the daemon?

Also, what do `pseudoOuts` represent?

Comment: As far as I know, `pseudoOuts` are the "decoy" outputs used for the ring signature. In your example there are 4 `pseudoOuts`, which corresponds to the minimum mixin of 4 that is enforced on testnet.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE Thanks for answering. How are these "decoy outputs" used in the ring signature? I don't find this term in MRL-0005.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in my post to MRL Issue [#6](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/issues/6), I now figured out what `pseudoOuts` mean. Assuming the `outPk` means the output commitments, what I'd like to know (assuming the ring signature is valid), would be to see the following hold:

```
sum_j{pseudoOuts[j]} = sum_i{outPk[i]} + fee*H
```

What I'm missing in Luigi's JS code is a way to get `fee*H`.

Edit:
Luigi kindly answered my question!
Here's the full JS code you can try at: https://xmr.llcoins.net/

```
> var H = ge_scalarmult(cn_fast_hash(ge_scalarmult_base("0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")), "0800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
undefined
> H
"8b655970153799af2aeadc9ff1add0ea6c7251d54154cfa92c173a0dd39c1f94"
> var fee = swapEndian(d2h256("30000000000"));
undefined
> fee
"00AC23FC06000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> var feeH = ge_scalarmult(H, fee);
undefined
> feeH
"527e4c0b6e34f948fb59ab014ec8eedf9eccfda4930a0b30d12790a0ec0d91f2"
> var pseudoOuts = [ "276f03ba8c7852cb545830f7fedcdcd08789675d2a6c265bea236d0de90f6b11", "c611cc551db3b05ad6e5dba4ce89a8eeeb18317d8b565031941e98b6b9b8db4f", "8a088f1ccd11dd1633a663538faa9cb18c157b4fd37c421697a6356b4d7a98f6", "9e1238add1c1a4712904e5d5d8913482dcd6d31af166bc73918fd8148a42f22b"];
undefined
> var outPk = [ "f9cabc6b0fd32822feb3e13c70b54b2cdc2a3ce7c88ac661c29ab20732e2974f", "cfb010382648e11d7d5744fe8051c8606f31c901f9ede5b7e392f73790f9e7f8"]
undefined
> var sumIn = ge_add(ge_add(ge_add(pseudoOuts[0], pseudoOuts[1]), pseudoOuts[2]), pseudoOuts[3]);
undefined
> var sumOut = ge_add(ge_add(outPk[0], outPk[1]), feeH);
undefined
> sumIn
"a340fb56b64d831d4f06079f1fc4d507a7a2d1b0107ea7814c626c7394190da6"
> sumOut
"a340fb56b64d831d4f06079f1fc4d507a7a2d1b0107ea7814c626c7394190da6"
```

Comment: fee*H should be easy to do in the JS (I assume you're using a browser console to access it?). You can generate H with `var H = generate_key_derivation_2(cn_fast_hash(sec_key_to_pub("0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")), "0800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");`. Then convert the fee in AU to a 32byte string and scalarmult with something like `var feeH = generate_key_derivation_2(H, swapEndian(("0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" + parseInt(<your AU fee here>).toString(16)).slice(-64)));`

Comment: I like it a lot. :)

Since you exposed my, uh, dumb function names (or was that me), I renamed/aliased some of them. `ge_scalarmult` is now the name for `generate_key_derivation_2` (both still work) and `ge_scalarmult_base` now also works for `sec_key_to_pub`. I also added a new `d2h256` conversion function to convert any size decimal value to padded hex.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced some function names! Your function `d2h256 ` seems to give me the hex string in the wrong order:  `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006FC23AC00`

Comment: Yes it's big endian like "normal" numbers. If you check the function, there's a comment right above it explaining as such. :)