# How does RingCT work?

Tags: ringct, encryption

How does RingCT work in hiding transaction amounts and how can it ensure that an output with 3 monero is used in a transaction with outputs of 1 and 2 monero but not 2 and 2?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4042/how-does-ringct-work-with-without-coefficients

Comment: in laymans https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/880/eli5-how-does-ringct-work