# Transaction structure: Question about ecdhInfo

Tags: ringct, transaction-data, cryptography, confidential-transactions

[This question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/can-i-manually-check-consistency-of-pedersen-commitments-in-ringct) by kenshi84 shows how the `pseudoOuts` and `outPk` fields can be validated by anyone (without knowing any of the private keys involved), by checking that `sumIn === sumOut`:

```
> var H = ge_scalarmult(cn_fast_hash(ge_scalarmult_base("0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")), "0800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
undefined
> H
"8b655970153799af2aeadc9ff1add0ea6c7251d54154cfa92c173a0dd39c1f94"
> var fee = swapEndian(d2h256("30000000000"));
undefined
> fee
"00AC23FC06000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
> var feeH = ge_scalarmult(H, fee);
undefined
> feeH
"527e4c0b6e34f948fb59ab014ec8eedf9eccfda4930a0b30d12790a0ec0d91f2"
> var pseudoOuts = ["276f03ba8c7852cb545830f7fedcdcd08789675d2a6c265bea236d0de90f6b11", "c611cc551db3b05ad6e5dba4ce89a8eeeb18317d8b565031941e98b6b9b8db4f", "8a088f1ccd11dd1633a663538faa9cb18c157b4fd37c421697a6356b4d7a98f6", "9e1238add1c1a4712904e5d5d8913482dcd6d31af166bc73918fd8148a42f22b"];
undefined
> var outPk = [ "f9cabc6b0fd32822feb3e13c70b54b2cdc2a3ce7c88ac661c29ab20732e2974f", "cfb010382648e11d7d5744fe8051c8606f31c901f9ede5b7e392f73790f9e7f8"]
undefined
> var sumIn = ge_add(ge_add(ge_add(pseudoOuts[0], pseudoOuts[1]), pseudoOuts[2]), pseudoOuts[3]);
undefined
> var sumOut = ge_add(ge_add(outPk[0], outPk[1]), feeH);
undefined
> sumIn
"a340fb56b64d831d4f06079f1fc4d507a7a2d1b0107ea7814c626c7394190da6"
> sumOut
"a340fb56b64d831d4f06079f1fc4d507a7a2d1b0107ea7814c626c7394190da6"
```

It's nice to have working javascript code (you can try by opening a browser console [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/)), and I wonder if my question can be answered in a similar way.

I've noticed that the `ecdhInfo` field wasn't used in the above javascript code. Is there a way to validate `ecdhInfo` too, without knowing any private keys? Or is this not necessary?

For reference, here's `rct_signatures` from kenshi84's question again:

```
{
    "type": 2, 
    "txnFee": 30000000000, 
    "pseudoOuts":["276f03ba8c7852cb545830f7fedcdcd08789675d2a6c265bea236d0de90f6b11", "c611cc551db3b05ad6e5dba4ce89a8eeeb18317d8b565031941e98b6b9b8db4f", "8a088f1ccd11dd1633a663538faa9cb18c157b4fd37c421697a6356b4d7a98f6", "9e1238add1c1a4712904e5d5d8913482dcd6d31af166bc73918fd8148a42f22b"], 
    "ecdhInfo": [ {
        "mask": "c626b75f726e88a26fc74c1bb508fa9358c0896a7635d0f1256c7f43f0217706", 
        "amount": "63c1d97047ff515ccd5ca271f4e5013b9c1092c25307207a0ff037b13f492c00"
      }, {
        "mask": "73b4367f9b143c0a453598f85761698c4548e890fa52a05b4e28183126525008", 
        "amount": "81b48b46e79b458a234ad36d3d0890f89e30d50cc18a687dd94fd0ef3417da0f"
      }], 
    "outPk": [ "f9cabc6b0fd32822feb3e13c70b54b2cdc2a3ce7c88ac661c29ab20732e2974f", "cfb010382648e11d7d5744fe8051c8606f31c901f9ede5b7e392f73790f9e7f8"]
 }
```

Comment: Assuming these fields are symmetrically encrypted, it would seem plausible that only the recipient can validate them. How would the recipient then check that mask and amount are correct?

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/421ab3119ce8ccbf73ad12d736d3daa897fa0347/src/ringct/rctSigs.cpp#L1020-L1041) seems relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the ecdhInfo mask and amount are encrypted by the sender of the transaction.

Both are encrypted (each in a slightly different way) using the transaction's shared secret (aR).

Therefore both encrypted values will be randomly distributed, and thus cannot be validated by a third party.

If the sender of the transaction had somehow written faulty values into the transaction, the only consequence would be that the outputs created by the transaction would be unspendable.

The code that encrypts and decrypts the ecdhInfo values is here: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/2b00899bb28e09f0c44813689acc0add73832215/src/ringct/rctOps.cpp#L447

Comment: Just to be sure... so `ecdhInfo` and `outPk` must have the same length, and for all `i`, `0 <= i < outPk.length`, the receiver would check that `ge_add(ge_scalarmult_base(ecdhDecode(ecdhInfo[i].mask, aR)), ge_scalarmult(ecdhDecode(ecdhInfo[i].amount, aR), H))` equals `outPk[i]`?

Comment: Yes, to both. Technically your code wouldn't compile, but you've clearly understood the principle that the ecdhInfo is there to communicate the components of the output Pedersen commitments to the recipient, so that the recipient is then able to properly construct a RingCT proof that references those outputs as  inputs in a subsequent transaction.