# Recover an XMO transaction

Tags: transaction-data, monero-forks

I have an XMR Monero wallet on my MAC computer, went through Changelly and sent (accidentally) XMO to it instead of XMR. Everything was correct except I sent XMO instead of XMR. I have looked at a couple of posts but they seem to be referring to recovering an XMR transaction to an XMR wallet. I have installed monero-original-v0.11.2.0 CLI wallet with the same seed words and now have the same address as my XMR wallet. That's where I'm stuck, the wallet is sync'd but I still don't have any balance. I also tried creating a wallet from a specific date. Can anyone help with where to go from here?
thanks - H Mark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.11 to CLI or GUI v0.12) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-created-pe)

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Comment: I looked at this guide but it is referring to the 0.12 wallet which seems to be the XMR wallet, not XMO. I need to recover XMO from a 4/14/2018 transaction. Doesn't it have to go into an XMO wallet and then I could transfer it to XMR? But I don't know how to get the transaction to show up. I'm new at this so patience is appreciated. - h mark

Comment: Do you know whether the XMO transaction was mined? You can check by inputting the transaction hash / ID on an XMO block explorer. If it was actually mined, Changelly received your XMO and you can't reclaim it.

Comment: Yes, I checked the transaction and both the incoming transaction from me to Changelly and the outgoing transaction from Changelly to me was mined (I guess) because I can look it up with Changelly's outgoing transaction hash on the appropriate coin block chains. The problem, as I see it, is the incoming transaction to Changelly has an amount. The outgoing transaction to me in the XMO block chain is there but with zero amount. Does that not seem like an error? I'm new at this and maybe I don't understand why it would be zero.

Comment: Also, here are the two transactions in that particular XMO block: this first one is NOT mine... hash=6b61a7a7c68f0edeb4f9e5dbe60fc7b0e024bbcae5a3f2eef187d631774137f7 fee=0.000000000000 total amt=4.804779945493 size=95   //  
This following one is mine: hash=9367fff02a34cb0cac49779b54dbb452ea64c75b7ee252e47be6fcdd26565e52 fee=0.000000000000 total amt=0.000000000000 size=13058. See what I mean?

Comment: That simply implies one transaction has pre-RingCT inputs, whereas the other has RingCT inputs. See: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/what-is-output-in-block/8133#8133 | `size=95 //` That's simply a coinbase transaction, see: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3908/44

Comment: Thanks for taking time to educate me. I think if I can sync to the correct XMO blockchain instead of XMR, that I could receive my xmo balance. I'm following instructions from: https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/8cxv99/how_to_claim_monero_original_xmo/. Can you comment on this Monerod sync error  "...peer claims higher version that we think..."? Should I stop that sync and download a more recent update of Monerod?

Comment: Just want to thank you for helping me. I was able to sync to the xmo blockchain, install the xmo wallet, and recover my xmo.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Seems the question has been answered by dEBRUYNE in comments above.  Therein lies the answer.

Use your XMR seed with the XMO client to get your funds back.  You can still exchange them to XMR at Changelly, but I wouldn't count on that being the case forever, as XMO is not, as far as I know, used by anyone, at all, for anything.

XmanXU has posted on github the fork, though I would not recommend using it.  The person advertised the publication on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/8456rs/introducing_monero_original_xmo/) as well, to near-universal disapproval, by the way. It seems to be a scam coin that actually hurts the privacy of XMR itself.

Comment: thanks much for the repy - can you elaborate on how to use my XMR seed with the XMO client? Since Changelly transaction has sent it to the XMR seed which is unique... ??

Comment: i'm new at this so maybe confused a bit. I have an XMR wallet. I just installed what I suspect to be the XMO wallet which is a command line thing. So are you saying use my existing XMR wallet seed words with the newly installed XMO wallet?

Comment: Follow dEBRUYNE's advice first.  dEBRUYNE is a highly respected member of the community.

Comment: I think debruyne is saying this, however.  Download official, old release of xmr at [github](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/releases).  The October 27th hydra.  Then try to load up that up with your xmr seed.  The old xmr client should be compatible with your xmo.    You sent (some coin, ex bitcoin) to changelly and wanted to get xmr in return, but accidentallly clicked xmo, correct?  I think debruyne is confused on your question a little.  Or maybe I am.

Comment: Yes - exactly. I sent some coin to Changelly and wanted XMR but accidentally clicked on XMO. Changelly Support states the transaction was successful and it's not their problem. But here is the issue: I can look up the incoming hash on the block chain and see the correct amount of incoming coin. But when I look up the outgoing hash transaction in the XMO block chain, the transaction exists but is for zero amount. Support tells me that XMO is encrypted and that is why it is zero. But there are other transactions in the chain showing actual amounts. I think I've been ripped off, more than less.

Comment: My wallet isn't going to sync for an amount more than zero unless there is something I don't understand about the block chain and transactions (highly likely). I followed dEBUYNE's instructions and was able to load the old XMO wallet with seed and obtain the same address that Changelly sent to. But I still can't get a balance and believing that is because the blockchain transaction is zero amount. If wrong please correct me. I'm kind of fighting with Changelly Support who just keep saying Sync Wallet. I have.

Comment: Also want to thank you for taking time to assist and responding. Per above comment to dEBRUYNE, I was able to recover my XMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get my XMO back into a wallet and then transfer it somewhere else. The GUI wallet will not work. I don't know why except that it "seems" to be syncing to the wrong chain. I had to download the CLI (command line interface) wallet and run the Monerod application from a terminal. It took many days for the sync to complete and there were many errors appearing as it did so. When the sync completely finished. I used my original seed words and password to recreate a wallet with the same address as the XMO was sent to. Only then could I see my balance and I quickly sent it somewhere else to get the XMO out of that wallet and into a different coin. I can provide the commands to recreate the wallet, etc., but I would have to research it on the Internet. 
To answer where your XMO coin is... it's simply a blockchain transaction. When you sync the appropriate XMO blockchain and open the appropriate wallet with the receiving address, the XMO will appear there. You can delete the wallet and recreate it because the record of where the coin is supposed to be is in the blockchain. That's my very basic understanding of it from many days of trying to recover my XMO and figure out what was happening. Sync to the correct blockchain, recreate your wallet, and you will have your coin. However, if you don't have your seed words and password used to create the address, I don't know what you can do. Those are necessary to recreate a wallet with the matching address.

Comment: btw, here is the link to the right monero cli wallet - i forgot to add it above:

Comment: https://github.com/XmanXU/monero-original/releases. it's monero-original-0.11.3.0.zip for pc or .tgz for mac or Linux